# Copy notes item (mime part) to more other documents

Tags: xpages

Currently I'm using a main document for creating kind a survey in Xpages. The user can use a richt text editor to define the content of the text, that has to be answered.

This content is saved as Mime-Part and allows colors and images. Looking e.g. like this:

[image]

Now I want to copy this item "Content" to some other response documents which provide the opportunity to answer for all those people who have to. So I copy the NotesItem "Content" to those new response documents:

```
var content:NotesItem = wfDoc.getFirstItem("Content");
while (receivers.hasNext()) {           
        var user:String = receivers.next();
        //Sets the fields for the new response document
        var docResp:NotesDocument = database.createDocument();
        docResp.copyItem(content);
[...]
```

But this only works the first time. The first response doc also gets a new item called "Content" containing Mime-Part. All other documents get a Richtext-Item.

First response doc:

[image]
[image]

Second response doc:

[image]
[image]

**Question**: How can I make sure, that all the content including the formatting will be copied to all my response docs?

Comment: Are you setting session.setConvertMIME(false) before copying the item? That might prevent it being converted from mime, not sure.

Comment: Seems to work fine! I've tried this before, but put it also in front of the getFirstItem line, and it didn't work. Now it's like this: session.setConvertMIME(false);   docResp.copyItem(content);   session.setConvertMIME(true); Add this as an answer and I will accept it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you setting session.setConvertMIME(false) before copying the item? That might prevent it being converted from mime, not sure.